# How to allow some components to be added to AEM Experience Fragment (using design)?

Tags: aem, crx

Designs are used for such cases if working with simple pages. I've tried adding /etc/design for Facebook Experience Fragment. I've added cq:designPath to the template. But I can't configure the right structure for this design.

Right now my design looks like this:

/etc/design/experience-fragment:

_jcr:content (with sling:resourceType set to wcm/core/components/designer)

__experience-fragment-template-facebook

___initial

____root (with components property specified).

No new components are allowed to be added to my experience fragments though.
I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to achieve this using Editable Page Template and it's components policies option.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before attempting to answer more questions.

Comment: facing similar issue. Can not add components for which I have model java created in core section but other custom components we can add. any suggestion?